# Can UILocalNotification fire a custom method when App is in background mode?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, notifications

Well the title is self explained. I want to create an App that can manage programmed **local** notifications when App is in background mode. Notifications works smoothly but I want to fire a custom method when the alert is fired.

Is it possible?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it can be done. You can do somethng like this:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:17.0 target:self selector:@selector(makeNotificationRequest:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)makeNotificationRequest:(NSTimer *)timer
{
    CLLocation *location = [[AppHelper appDelegate] mLatestLocation];
    NSMutableDictionary *paramDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

#ifdef _DEBUG
    [paramDic setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"77.586"] forKey:@"Lat"];
    [paramDic setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"12.994"] forKey:@"long"];
#else
    [paramDic setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",location.coordinate.latitude] forKey:@"Lat"];
    [paramDic setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",location.coordinate.longitude] forKey:@"long"];
#endif

    WNetwork *mNetwork = [[WNetwork alloc] init];
    [mNetwork makeRequsetWithURL:URL_Showbeeps type:JBJsonParser paramDictionary:paramDic delegate:self];
    [mNetwork autorelease];
    NSLog(@"URL HIT%@",paramDic);
    [paramDic autorelease];
}
```

And to customize your action on alert you can use this:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification {
    UIApplicationState state = [application applicationState];
    if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {
        ;
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s documented that, when the app goes background, the timers stops ticking

Comment: see if ur method is too large as in u doin to many actions in it it will dismiss the method bt if u optimise the method to do only the important stuff it will work....

Comment: Ok I’ll try this code as soon as I can and keep you noticed. Thank you

Comment: This code actually didn’t work for my intentions. I want to run the custom method when the app is backgrounded and when the local notification is fired. My method isn’t too large... now it contents just a NSLog line. And it’s not fired when the local notification do.

Answer (score 1):

If the app were in the foreground then you would want the  `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification` method of `UIApplicationDelegate`, however the documentation suggests that this will not be called when the app is in the background.

You can get a list of local notifications by calling `scheduledLocalNotifications` on your `UIApplication` instance - you can then poll these for their times and schedule a function to call at that time in your background mode. This won't necessarily 100% match up with when the Local Notification fires though, but I think it's as close as the App Store guidelines will let you get.

You can also present your own Local Notifications when you are in background mode by calling the `presentLocalNotificationNow:` method:

https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIApplication/presentLocalNotificationNow:

so you could work around this by just presenting your own notifications and not scheduling them for the OS to deliver.

If you are trying to access Local Notifications from other applications then I don't think this is allowed.

Comment: The method `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification` fires when user touch the notification, not when notification occurs if the app is in background mode, as documented in Apple docs. But thank you for your time :)

Comment: That's not true, actually. It fires when the notification should be displayed if the application is in the foreground, so that the application itself can choose to display it if it wants to.

Comment: I've revised my answer now it's clearer what you're after. I hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your time Benjie but I’m not explaining clearly. The notification MUST be scheduled. So I can't use `presentLocalNotificationNow:`. For me is useless. The thing is: I have a number of `UILocalNotification` objects scheduled. They will fire according to their `fireDate` property. I want to fire a custom method when each of the `UILocalNotification` fires. I’m investigating now with `addObserver`. No results for now :(

Comment: `[self performSelector:@selector(blah) withObject:nil afterDelay:[fireDate timeIntervalSinceNow]]` will run the `blah` method at (very close to) the same time as the local notification fires (i.e. fireDate).

Comment: I’m going to try this right now, but... will the timer of the selector continue counting when the app goes background?... I’ll post the answer here. Thnx

Comment: It will if you set it up in your background runloop. Here's some documentation on the background modes your app can have: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20

Comment: What are you trying to get it to do, anyway?

Comment: Actually the method I want to fire contains just a NSLog statement, to test the calling. And is called only when the app goes to foreground mode again.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I meant what is your use case for calling a method when the UILocalNotification fires?

Comment: Each UILocalNotification is like a scheduled alarm. Fires at a determined date and time. When a UILocalNotification fires (and actually it fires ok) a method with some actions must be fired in order to make the app work. It’s like a scheduled tasks app. Sorry but I cannot be more explicit with the app purpose... My boss want to keep it a "secret"

Answer (score 1):

No ..no custom methods are defined while app is running in background..Once an notification is fired we can;t change the alert message also. But nice when we show the alert message then by clicking the yes button to the alert take you to the one method called app is Running in Background which is in AppDelegate.m file